# Calculating price: "Operator / not compatible"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, math

```
 function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int, uint8) {
    (
      uint80 roundID,
      int price,
      uint startedAt,
      uint timeStamp,
      uint80 answeredInRound
  ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

    uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();
    return (price, decimals);
  }


  function priceInEth() external view returns (uint) {
      uint txtPriceUsd = 2;
      (int price, uint8 decimals) = getLatestPrice();

      // --------------------------- PROBLEM IS HERE ---------------------------
      return price / txtPriceUsd;
  }
```

I'm just learning Solidity math, so I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work.

**What I'm trying to do**:

I have an integer `price` (a USD value, I'd like to have it be a float — for simplicity I'm trying integers first). Then I fetch ETH latest price in USD, divide it to figure out the price in ETH.

But there is something going on that is preventing me from calculating it.

Can someone give me some pointers on why that is? And how I might go about fixing that? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just realized I'd need to make some adjustments to return value of `getLatestPrice()` which is `(price, decimals)`. And insert the decimal in the price to get a correct view of it's price (it's returned as integer).

Comment: What are you possibly hoping to achieve by dividing a `uint` of value `2` by something??? It's gonna be either `2` or `1` or revert due to division by zero

Comment: And BTW, your `priceInEth` function returns a `uint`, but acts like... well... what exactly is the idea in returning `txtPriceUsd  / price` when, for example, `price == -1`?

Comment: ooops I wrote the question wrong, just updated qurstion. I'm trying to get the price of `price` in ETH